# How to pass a temp table as a parameter into a separate stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes an input parameter `@CategoryKeys varchar`, and parses its contents into a temp table, `#CategoryKeys`.

```
        -- create the needed temp table.
        CREATE TABLE #CategoryKeys
          (
             CategoryKey SMALLINT
          );

        -- fill the temp table if necessary
        IF Len(rtrim(ltrim(@CategoryKeys))) > 0
          BEGIN
              INSERT INTO #CategoryKeys
                          (CategoryKey)
              SELECT value
              FROM   dbo.String_To_SmallInt_Table(@CategoryKeys, ',');
          END
```

If the temp table has rows, I would like to pass the table into a separate stored procedure. How would I go about creating a parameter in the separate procedure to hold the temp table?

Comment: Instead of passing a comma-separated list in the first place, have you thought about using [table-valued parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)? Also have you read [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)?

Comment: Or XML, as SQL Server offers support for XML data type...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you create a #TEMP table, the "scope" is bigger than just the procedure it is created in.

Below is a sample:

```
IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspProc002'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProc002]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspProc002 
AS

BEGIN

/* Uncomment this code if you want to be more explicit about bad "wiring" */
/*
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NULL
begin
        THROW 51000, 'The procedure expects a temp table named #TableOne to already exist.', 1;  
end
*/

    /* Note, I did not Create #TableOne in this procedure.  It "pre-existed".  An if check will ensure that it is there.  */
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
        Insert into #TableOne ( SurrogateKey , NameOf ) select 2001, 'Hello-From-uspProc002'
    end

END


GO



IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspProc001'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProc001]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspProc001 (
@Param1 int
)
AS

BEGIN


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TableOne
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TableOne
    ( 
    SurrogateKey int , 
    NameOf varchar(12)
    )

    Insert into #TableOne ( SurrogateKey , NameOf ) select 1001, 'Hello-From-uspProc001'

    Select 'before-nested-call' as MyStatus1, * from #TableOne

    EXEC dbo.uspProc002 

    Select 'after-nested-call' as MyStatus1, * from #TableOne

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TableOne
    end


END


GO




exec dbo.uspProc001 0
```

**HAVING SAID THAT, PLEASE DO NOT CODE UP ALOT OF THESE.  ITS THE SQL EQUIVALENT OF A GLOBAL VARIABLE AND IT IS DIFFICULT TO MAINTAIN AND BUG PRONE.**

Answer (score 33):

While understanding scoping addresses the direct need, thought it might be useful to add a few more options to the mix to elaborate on the suggestions from the comments.

1. Pass XML into the stored procedure
2. Pass a table-valued parameter into the stored procedure

**1. Pass XML into the stored procedure**

With XML passed into a parameter, you can use the XML directly in your SQL queries and join/apply to other tables:

```
CREATE PROC sp_PassXml
    @Xml XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT T.Node.value('.', 'int') AS [Key]
    FROM @Xml.nodes('/keys/key') T (Node)
END
GO
```

Then a call to the stored procedure for testing:

```
DECLARE @Text XML = '<keys><key>1</key><key>2</key></keys>'
EXEC sp_PassXml @Text
```

Sample output of a simple query.

```
Key
-----------
1
2
```

**2. Pass a table-valued parameter into the stored procedure**

First, you have to define the user defined type for the table variable to be used by the stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE KeyTable AS TABLE ([Key] INT)
```

Then, you can use that type as a parameter for the stored proc (the `READONLY` is required since only `IN` is supported and the table cannot be changed)

```
CREATE PROC sp_PassTable
    @Keys KeyTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * FROM @Keys
END
GO
```

The stored proc can then be called with a table variable directly from SQL.

```
DECLARE @Keys KeyTable
INSERT @Keys VALUES (1), (2)
EXEC sp_PassTable @Keys
```

Note: If you are using .NET, then you can pass the SQL parameter from a DataTable type matching the user defined type.

Sample output from the query:

```
Key
-----------
1
2
```

Comment: While I have the accepted answer to the question, I am upvoting this because "just because the scope works".....doesn't mean its a good solution.  Treating #tempTables like a global variable is bad routine practice.  And I do exactly this, I pass xml all the time to promote set based operations to avoid cursors and RBAR.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer: even if it is not directly answering the question

Answer (score 1):

Stored proc that uses temp table

```
CREATE OR ALTER Procedure Engine.TestProcTempTable
AS
BEGIN
  --DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestProcTempTable ;
  SELECT * from #TestProcTempTable;
END
```

Create put data in to temp table which will be used by SP

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestProcTempTable ;
select * into #TestProcTempTable from <TABLE_NAME>;
execute Engine.TestProcTempTable
```