# select from temp table multiple times in a proceduer

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

in mysql I have two stored procedure `sp1` and `sp2`.
`sp2` creates a temp table called `temp_tbl`.
`sp1` calls `sp2` and uses `temp_tbl` multiple times in procedure. But when I run, I get error `Can't reopen table: 'temp_tbl'`!
I tried to call `sp2` before each select, but again the same error occurred.
Also using different aliases for temp table didn't solved the problem.
Any solution to handle this?

Comment: Please have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041595/7564182), sounds like the syntax you are searching for.

Comment: tnx @Myonara, but the answer you mentioned is in sql server syntax. In mysql, table name can not pass through param.