# Unknown number of parameters passing to a stored procedure from client.How to handle this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which inserts some records from `Archive` table into the main table.

My problem is that the client has multiple checkboxes in his grid and he/she can check any number of checkboxes. Each checkbox represents a record in the `Archive` table. Each record is identified by `orderNo`. On the basis of `orderNo` I want to make a Stored Procedure that takes a record from the `Archive` table and inserts this into the main table.

My question: How do I handle an unknown number of parameters in this Stored Procedure *effectively*? In pseudo-code:

```
create procedure moveRecords(what parameters i should take here)
as 
begin
insert into mainTable(orderNo,date,siteID) select orderNo,date,siteID from 
ArchiveTable where orderNo=<here what i write>
```

The client could send 1 parameter, 2, 3, 10, 20 parameter etc we don't know. Something like the following:

```
exec moveRecords(any no. of parameters)
```

I came up with a solution like the following:

1. By putting all `orderNo` (sent by the client) into one `temp_Table` and retrieve these from `temp_Table` in my Stored Procedure.
2. At the server side we take all `orderNo` in an array and call procedure on the basis of this array.

I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: **any no. of parameters**, means any number of records? and those are got if checkbox is checked?

Comment: @Bharadwaj:-yes you are right

Comment: you got the answer already, that what I was about to tell you if you said yes.

Comment: @Bharadwaj:- i did not understand what you have said?

Comment: Michal already posted that answer. That's what I meant

Answer (score 5):

If you use MSSQL 2008 or newer you can use TVP (Table Valued Parameters). Here is an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) describing them. And here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) about using TVP from C#.

TVP are pretty easy to use:

1. Firstly you have to define a type of TVP by using `CREATE TYPE dbo.NameOfYourType ...` command.
2. Then you have to modify your stored procedure. For example: `create procedure moveRecords(@Input dbo.NameOfYourType READONLY) ...`.
3. Then call this stored procedure from C# as any other stored procedure. TVP parameters are represented by `DataTable` in C#.

Comment: :-i could not understand your 3 step please can you define it more.How to insert  values in our Table type

Comment: Did you read a question pointed by me? There is an answer that refers to an article that point by point explains how to use TVP from C#. You can also read this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can pass xml and parse it inside procedure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33967918/5088253). This sa,mple also describe table valued parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure Usp_Testproc
(
@iordernumber int
)
as 
begin
insert into mainTable(orderNo,date,siteID) 
select orderNo,date,siteID from ArchiveTable where orderNo=@iordernumber
```

Comment: you code is only for one parameter not what i need?